# Docker flow proxy multiple domains forwarding

Tags: docker, haproxy

I am running multiple redmine instances over docker where the web requests are handled with [docker flow proxy](https://proxy.dockerflow.com/usage/) ACL's so that every ACL is performing the link  between the name of the running docker container with its domain as configured in the file *haproxy.cfg*

My question is if it is possible to point 2 different domains to the same redmine instance. I have been looking in the docker flow proxy configuration but I'm not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done by modifying the label serviceDomain as:

```
com.df.serviceDomain=domain.one.com, domain.two.com
```

In the docker-compose.yml file